# NGINX -Rewrite base url keeping part of url

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have some several proxies for my api calls through nginx. For example

http://localhost:5000/application/api1/get/user will be redirected to

https://example.com/application/api1/get/user

```
location ~* "^/api1" {
   proxy_pass https://example.com;
}
```

Now I have to redirect some calls from:

http://localhost:5000/application/api2/get/data to https://example.com/api2/get/data

Note: That I do not need the application this time...

I have tried this :

```
location ~* "^/api2" {
   rewrite ^/application/(.*) /$1
   proxy_pass https://example.com;
}
```

But it does not seem to work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this...

```
location /application/api2/ {
   include proxy_params;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
   proxy_pass https://example.com/api2/;
}
```

we can discuss further too...